# Basis of invariant tensors of rank n in three dimensions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

[This is a question motivated by theoretical physics, so apologies if the language is rough...]

In three dimensions the spaces of invariant (or isotropic) tensors of rank $n$ have dimensions 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 6, 15, 36, 91, 232, ... (see [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsotropicTensor.html)). Equivalently, this is the number of trivial representations in the $n$-fold tensor product of the fundamental representation of $SO(3)$.

Any invariant tensor can be expressed as a linear combination of products of Kronecker deltas and (for odd rank) one [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) (see [this note](http://jeffreymepstein.com/IsotropicTensorsNote.pdf), which contains references to the original literture), but in general there will be linear independences.

The dimensions are given by the [Riordan numbers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X99000540?via%3Dihub), of which there are many combinatoric interpretations. My question is: **is there an explicit bijection between one of these interpretations and a linearly independent basis** of invariant tensors?

For example, in the case of $SU(2)$ there is such a bijection, expressed in terms of noncrossing  pairings on a circle, with each pairing corresponding to $\epsilon_{ab}$ (in quantum mechanics we say a two-spin singlet state). This is originally due to [Rumer, Teller, and Weyl](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN252457811_1932?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B503%5D%7D), and generalized by [Temperley and Lieb](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1971.0067). See [this paper](https://journals.jps.jp/doi/10.1143/JPSJ.59.482) for a more recent discussion

Comment: Presumably there should be a way to do this using Kuperberg's webs: https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9712003

Comment: Hi Austen (who I met at UVa?) A small correction: this is not originally due to RTW in 1932 but to Alfred Kempe in 1893 https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s1-25.1.343

Comment: Hi Malek! I was wondering if you'd put me right with some 19th century invariant theory. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Planar partitions with no singletons works.  You need to pick for each $n>1$ some map with certain properties.  One way to do this is to just fix a preferred trivalent tree of each size and interpret each vertex as a cross product.  For example, one arbitrary choice gives the map $V^{\otimes n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $$v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n \mapsto (((v_1 \times v_2) \times v_3) \ldots \times v_{n-1})\ldots) \cdot v_n.$$

It’s a little awkward that the above formula isn’t invariant under cyclic permutation of the variables, so you have to arbitrarily pick a "starting point" for each connected component.  A better way is to write the non-crossing partition of 2n strands where each end connects to its neighbor and then attach a bunch of “2nd Jones-Wenzl projectors” (i.e. the projection from the square of the 2d to the 3d) along the boundary in an interleaving way (ie connecting each strand to its *other* neighbor).

As discussed in comments, the JW2 part can be interpreted as rewriting the vector in terms of the corresponding sum of Pauli matrices.  If we let $\sigma_v$ denote the sum of Pauli matrices corresponding to $v$, then the rotationally invariant map is just the trace of the product of Pauli matrices:
$$v_1 \otimes \ldots v_n \mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(\sigma_{v_1} \sigma_{v_2} \cdots \sigma_{v_n}).$$

This was the formula for a single connected component, so the general formula is a product over connected components of the trace of the product of Pauli matrices for each component.

Another approach, using a different set, is to take n pairs of boundary points and look at non-crossing partitions of 2n points such that no pair connects to itself.  Then just interpret this in SU(2) by embedding each 3-dimensional irrep inside the square of the 2-dimensional irrep.

Comment: The second description is Exercise 2.5 in Kuperberg's paper linked in comments.

Comment: So it is. Thanks! I'm struggling a bit to understand the first approach though... in particular "the preferred trivalent tree" and "the projection from the square of the 2d to the 3d"

Comment: The 2-dimensional rep of SU(2) tensor squares to 1+3, this means there's a map $\pi: V^{\otimes 2} \rightarrow V^{\otimes 2}$ which acts by 0 on the trivial summand and acts by the identity on the 3-dimensional summand.  This is what I mean by that projection.

Comment: "Preferred trivalent tree" just means you're making a completely arbitrary choice, say left always parenthesizing.  I'll add a formula to the text.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was actually playing with that map before, and indeed dropped it because of the lack of cyclic invariance. Thanks!

Comment: There must be some very classical name for the map that goes from a vector to a tensor product of two spinors in an SU(2)-invariant way?

Comment: Well in physics it's the Pauli matrices, I guess. Isn't the other direction the Hopf map? Incidentally, your Jones-Wenzl construction sounds exactly like what's called the AKLT state in spin-1 chains....

Comment: Ah, right, and if you think of them as matrices then "pairing" just becomes multiplication.  I will add a formula.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've correctly parsed the AKLT state, but yes that looks correct except that you need to do it on a circle instead of a line.